# How to change the hamburger menu from left to right in the multilingual ios application?

Tags: ios, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

Currently i am developing an iOS application which needs to be shown in the Arabic as well as the english languages. For this i am currently using the SWRevealviewcontroller. But i have a requirement that if the user chooses the Arabic language form the application settings the hamburger menu should move from left to right.
Please do tell how to do this. Or any specific tutorial will help this.

The code below is:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(languageChanged(_:)), name: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

        customSetup()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func languageChanged(_ note: Notification)
    {
        customSetup()
    }

    func customSetup()
    {
        let preferredLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages[0] as NSString
        print(preferredLanguage)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if preferredLanguage.substring(with: NSMakeRange(0, 2)) == "ar" {
            leftButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            leftButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))

            rightButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            rightButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

            revealViewController().rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RearTableViewController") as? RevealTableTableViewController
            revealViewController().rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as? RightViewController
        }
        else {
            revealViewController().rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as? RightViewController
            revealViewController().rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RearTableViewController") as? RevealTableTableViewController

            leftButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            leftButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

            rightButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            rightButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
        }
    }
}
```

But i am getting the following error at

```
  if preferredLanguage.substring(with: NSMakeRange(0, 2)) == "ar" {
            leftButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            leftButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))

            rightButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            rightButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

            revealViewController().rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RearTableViewController") as? RevealTableTableViewController
            revealViewController().rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as? RightViewController
        }
```

[unwrapped value: Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AzqV.png)

Comment: simple., set two revals, left and right , based on language , hiden your reval

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Machaa i edited the question with code. Getting some error at runtime. Please see the attached image paa..

Comment: are you seen the identifier name and class name, ensure once both are correct

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes they are same...

Comment: problem is excatly this line `RearTableViewController") as? RevealTableTableViewController` check spell mistake or else bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik   I checked the whole but no help... Shall i upload it in a git and please look to it? ..

Comment: https://github.com/Abbiee/arabicSwift3Hamburger

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the error comes when i click on the button "Button".

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik right view controller ... there is a single button ... That button click

Comment: i m not faced any issues, i can click both menu and right button, the slide perfectly opened

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik in right button click it opens a view controller.. There is a button in it. Click on it. You will see the crash

Comment: problem not in **customsetup** method , problem is here ***let rootviewcontroller: UIWindow = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!
        rootviewcontroller.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootnav")
        let mainwindow = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!)!
        mainwindow.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.6477, saturation: 0.6314, brightness: 0.6077, alpha: 0.8)
        UIView.transition(with: mainwindow, duration: 0.55001, options: transition, animations: { () -> Void in
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
         }***

Comment: your code is correct and fine, in here we need to update the root controller with out terminate the app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how to update the root controller

Answer (score 0):

You should create a another storyboard for it.